# Prefixing iOS shared App Group with TeamId

Tags: ios

tl;dr Does anyone prefix their shared App Group name with their TeamId?

We use an App Group for sharing data between our app and extension, and with another app of ours. I've been passing the suite name as "group.com.example" to NSUserDefaults -initWithSuiteName and NSFileManager -containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier and it's been working fine.

With iOS 10 I'm seeing an Xcode console error when starting my app:

```
[User Defaults] Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource. 
Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, 
detaching from cfprefsd
```

A known solution is to prefix our TeamId to the group, but we already have an app out there using the non-prefixed variant, so changing it in this new app will cause compatibility issues. Other than this msg on startup there's no discernible problem.

Here's what makes me wary: We shipped a similar Mac app a few months ago and were hit with an App Store validation error that forced us to use the TeamID on the Mac:

```
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature 
contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X. 
Specifically, value '[group.com.example]' for key 
'com.apple.security.application-groups' is not supported. This value 
should be a string or an array of strings, each starting with 
your TEAMID followed by a dot '.' .
```

Apple's docs and sample code don't mention the TeamID prefix at all, and my hunch is this isn't a change they'd be able to make without breaking a huge number of apps out there, but if this is a direction Apple is moving I'd rather deal with it now than later.

Does anyone have any authoritative knowledge about using the TeamID prefix or not on iOS? Anyone run into problems using it, or not?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the validation error and iOS 10 message! I wondered about the exact same thing. Peeking into `~/Library/Group Containers/`, most start with a `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)` instead of "group" (in fact, the only one is `group.com.apple.notes`.)